# How to create Lookup filter in Lightning Component

Tags: lightning

How to create Lookup filter in Lightning component. When will this feature be available?

Comment: you can use typeaheads if that goes with the requirement. Make a server call onchange of text in input and return matched results to controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This functionality will be available with Spring 17 release (Mid February)

https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/search?query=lookup+filter&version=spring17